# relative virtual path doesnt allow here

Tags: asp.net, extjs4, ext.net

I am getting this error.I am loading dynamically usercontrol with the store below

`'WebServiceAdmin.asmx/SayfaKaydetAjax'`  virtual path doesnt allow here.

here is the my store ;

```
  <ext:Store ID="strSayfa" runat="server">
                    <Proxy>
                        <ext:AjaxProxy Json="true" Url="WebServiceAdmin.asmx/TumSayfalar">
                            <ActionMethods Read="POST" />
                            <API Sync="WebServiceAdmin.asmx/SayfaKaydetAjax">

                            </API>
                            <Reader>
                                <ext:JsonReader Root="d" />
                            </Reader>
                            <Writer>
                                <ext:JsonWriter Encode="true" Root="data" />
                            </Writer>
                        </ext:AjaxProxy>
                    </Proxy>
                    <SyncParameters>
                        <ext:StoreParameter Name="action" Value="operation.action" Mode="Raw" />
                    </SyncParameters>
```

Comment: If you search the web for the error you're _actually_ getting, _"the relative virtual path is not allow here"_, you'll find that you have to use an absolute URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution I can find

```
 <API Sync="~/WebServiceAdmin.asmx/SayfaKaydetAjax">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Michael this answer is provided by the asker. :-)

Comment: :) yes yes asker is me